# Android - tutorials for OpenGL ES 2.0 using the NDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm looking to learn `OpenGL ES 2.0` on Android and the tutorials I've found are nearly all for using the `SDK with Java`. I want to use native code however so I want to do it through the NDK. 
The only tutorial/example I've found is the sample-stuff in the `NDK` itself.

Where can I find some `NDK OpenGL ES 2.0` tutorials?
If there are no good tutorials out there, is it possible to use the Java `OpenGL` tutorials to learn how to use it in the NDK as well? For example do the methods map 1:1 from java to native?

Comment: Good question. Such a pity there was no answer.

Comment: I'm in the same situation at the moment. Did you find any?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've created an example on how to combine UI done in Java with native NDK code that does all the OpenGL rendering. It is possible to do without resorting to GLSurfaceView and JNI calls for rendering each frame like done in the NDK sample.

See the code at https://github.com/tsaarni/android-native-egl-example

Comment: Greate job, i have test the sample ,really useful,thanks, but ,there is a issue on same devices, when i set the screenOrientation to landscape,seems opengl not rendering...,

Comment: Thanks! Could you post issue ticket on the project page and attach logcat logfile? Unfortunately I did not have too many devices to test on...

Comment: @tsaarni, Are you sure that your project uses `OpenGL ES 2.0`?

Comment: @CAMOBAP No, I suppose it calls only OpenGL ES 1.x functions, no dependency to GLES 2.0 as such.  However it requires Android API level 9 and Android NDK r5 or later.

Comment: I was also looking for OpenGL ES 2.0 dependency, but your build.gradle shows that you are using version 1.x. https://github.com/tsaarni/android-native-egl-example/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: @FuatCoşkun I'm not working with Android anymore but please contribute update to the example for GLES 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Check [this link](http://www.brucesutherland.co.uk/android-ndk/opengl-es-2-0-android-ndk-game-programming/). It concerns NDK and OpenGL issues, as well as several other related to game engine programming and more. I find it very interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a sample project on GitHub which demonstrates how to setup a EGL context from native code, using `SurfaceView` created in Java: [Teapots sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/teapots). In particular,  take a look at "more teapots" app and code in `ndk_helper` for context creation.

If you want to work without any Java code, then this sample should help you get started: [native activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity)

Edit: additionally, this link gives a higher level overview of relationship between Java `Surface`, it's native counterpart and EGL: [EGLSurfaces and OpenGL ES](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-egl-opengl)